# I have a json respons as followed using java. One of the field is a key:value pair of an array. And I have no idea how to get that as an array

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "volumeInfo": {
                "industryIdentifiers": [
                    {
                        "type": "ISBN_10",
                        "identifier": "0080509576"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ISBN_13",
                        "identifier": "9780080509570"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above json, I need to extract industryIdentifiers' identifier value without losing any digit.

I have tried using JSONArray but it eats up some of the digits

```
jsonObj.getJSONObject("items")
            .getJSONObject("volumeInfo").getJSONArray("industryIdentifiers")
                .getString(0);
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: which value? ISBN_10 or 13? Please check [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: @Prateek both of them

Comment: Index 0 of `industryIdentifiers` contains an object, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the json array first and then iterate through it to parse.

Use [`org.json`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180130)

```
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("volumeInfo")
            .getJSONArray("industryIdentifiers");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        String type = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("type");
        String identifier = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("identifier");
        System.out.println(type + " identifier : " + identifier);

    }
```

### Output on Java 9

```
ISBN_10 identifier : 0080509576
ISBN_13 identifier : 9780080509570
```

Comment: This is where I'm running into the issue here: Your code with Output "type: ISBN_10 identifier: 80509576". identifier should be ->"0080509576"

Comment: Not able to reproduce, its fine on my machine.

Comment: I'm using JSONArray. Could that be a problem? Where can I get JsonArray?

Comment: I’m using all that. Still no luck. Terminal window shows output with 8 digits. Kind of like treating it is an Integer 

Comment: what version of java are you using? and check what is `getString` it should be `if (object instanceof String) { return (String) object; }`

Comment: I’m using Java 8.

Comment: use latest org.json , if possible switch to java 9

Comment: I'm receiving a json directly. I'm receiving an xml. Then I'm using org.json to convert that XML string to JSONObject. And in that process it treats those identifiers as integers. Which is nuts. Your solution works.